# Access a file in the referencing dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# class library project with name ExampleLibrary1 in which I have to access a text file in project folder. I tried all the below ways for get directory path.

```
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string assemblyFolder1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string assemblyFolder2 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
string assemblyFolder3 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

I am referencing the dll in consoleapplication1 and invoking the code which accesses the text file. All the above methods give me the below output and unable to access the file.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\x64\Debug
C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\x64\Debug
file:///C:/Users/Desktop/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/ExampleLibrary1.DLL
C:\Users\shrallap\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\x64\Debug
```

My requirement is I have to read a file in ExampleLibrary1 code, script is also in ExampleLibrary1. But the code invocation happens from ConsoleApplication1

Comment: You need to either provide path to files somehow as you can't compute it, or include files in your project

Comment: which project to my console application? Because at some point I have to create nuget package out of ExampleLibrary1 project.

Comment: Console one. If you eventually going to build nuget out of your library it is reasonable approach. Indeed you can embed files to the library but it is less educational as you will learn less doing so.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear my code in library need to access the file. so console application is just me try to test my library. So I will need to have the file in library, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your question, your have a text file, let's call it "yourtextfile.bat" in the project folder of `ExampleLibrary1`, in the same folder where the file `ExampleLibrary1.csproj` is.

You ***cannot*** access it from your code. Project folder is where you organise your source code on the dev machine, on users' environment, there is no project folder.

Of course, you can use relative path like this to access it

```
..\\..\\..\\..\\ExampleLibrary1\\yourtextfile.bat
```

But it only works in debugging.

You have to copy the text file to the output folder at build, then it will be the same folder as the dll/exe, and you can access it without worrying about its actual path, just use relative path "yourtextfile.bat" to access it.

In .NET, relative path is relative to the [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) at runtime, usually the folder where exe resides if you double click to launch the exe. It is NOT relative to the project folder.

Comment: You have got everything right, except the part that I can have the yourtextfile.bat inside ExampleLibrary1.csproj say scripts folder of the project folders. So still there is no way to have text file as part of referenced library?

Comment: No. The key is having a copy of the file in the output folder, there is one “Copy to Output” option in the file properties pane that does this for you.